# Stretchable header like StackExchange

Tags: html, css, layout, header

How can I do with CSS a site layout like **webmaster.stackexchange.com** that the site is center and the header and footer is as long as the user's window resolution, while the content is in the center check image fs you dont get me and THANK YOU :-) for your help.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/strectch.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

Right click and see the source -- no one forbids you that.

But in short -- one of the possible ways (may not be the best) -- this will make content centered:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div id="page-body">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
    ...
```

**CSS**

```
#page-wrapper {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
#page-body {position: absolute; width: 980px; top: 0;}
```

You may need to use a bit different approach if you want to have background images on footer & header to cover whole window width.

Comment: this was supposed to be my line, "Right click and see the source -- no one forbids you that." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a 1x200 (skinny and tall) image containing a gradient, then use this CSS:

```
#header-bg {
    background: blue url(/my/stretchy/image.png) repeat-x top left;
    text-align: center;
}

#header-content {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

<div id="header-bg">
    <div id="header-content">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

You basically just have to tile it horizontally.

Comment: this works i guess but it doesn't quite seem semantic to me to wrap the content of the page inside the header.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="topBar">My Epic Top Bar</div>
<div id="page">
       All your lovely page junk goes here
</div>
html, body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#page 
{
 margin: 0 auto;
  width:500px;  
    margin-top:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#topBar {
 width:100%;
  height:40px;
   background-color:#ccc;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0; 
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto` on `#page` sets the top/bottom margin to 0 and the left/right margin to auto, centering it since it has a fixed width of 500px. Keep in mind you need to keep the top-margin equal to the height of the #topBar so that #topBar doesn't cover up any of #page

Answer (score 0):

The most cross-browser consistent manner is as has been mentioned: wrap your fixed width header content with an auto width wrapper.

For browsers that support it, you can make use of :before and :after to achieve a full width header without the extra div: http://css-tricks.com/9443-full-browser-width-bars/