# Centering text for non-image background header?

Tags: html, css

To continue off of this question: [Stretchable header like StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478926/stretchable-header-like-stackexchange). I am having issues being able to center my text for my website so it stays inside of the 960 grid container (I am using the [960 grid system](http://www.960.gs/)). Theirs 2 different ways I've tried:

.

1. Have my Logo and menu inside of the background div but this makes all of the text go way left on the screen outside of the 960px container.

   ```
   <div class="container_24">
     <div id="header-top-border" class="grid_24"></div>
     <div id="header-background" class="grid_24">
       <div class="grid_5">Logo</div>
       <div class="grid_19">Main Menu</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. I Have it outside of the logo and menu but this covers up everything included in my header (logo, header-top-border and menu).

   ```
   <div id="header-top-border" class="grid_24"></div> # not shown
   <div id="header-background" class="grid_24"></div> # covers all
   <div>Logo</div> # not shown
   <div>Main Menu</div> # not shown
   ```

Here is my css:

```
#header-background {
    background: rgb(144,191,34);
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you absolutely position an element, that element is removed from the document flow and positioned relative to the nearest parent element that has positioning applied. If no parent has positioning applied, it will be positioned relative to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code, you cant use `position: absolute;` with `margin: 0 auto;` trick, because that what "Scott Simpson" said on his comment, but if you need to use position absolute for `#header-background`, you can use the following code to help you :

First I suggest to use clearfix trick with container :

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

and i recommend to reset margin and padding for all elements or at least for `body`, so put this code on the first of first line of css file must loaded:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then edit your code to be like:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container_24 clearfix">
  <div id="header-top-border" class="grid_24"></div>
  <div id="header-background" class="grid_24">
    <div class="grid_5">Logo</div>
    <div class="grid_19">Main Menu</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

.container_24 {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#header-background {
    background: rgb(144,191,34);
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

Note what I made for `.container_24`.

I hope this will help you.

BTW: if you cant edit: the following line:

```
<div class="container_24">
```

To add `.clearfix` class, you can just edit css, so use `.container_24:after` instead of `.clearfix:after`, I hope this will make every thing good.